# Error reporting tool/service

Tags: architecture

I was wondering if there is any tool out there which could be easily integrated into my existing application infrastructure and handle the error reporting. Kind of a service.

It should allow me (as an application developer) to send unhandled errors into it .. e.g. using a webservice, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow none of the tools mentioned did fulfill my requests.

I have found one which meets the requirements best .. although it could require some more additions. (its open source so thats great)

- [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/).

Answer (score 1):

You should look for a [bug/issue tracking system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) with webservice interface. For example [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org) is very popular. It's has an [xml-rpc interface](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.0/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html) and client libraries for some langauages.

Answer (score 0):

For global capturing of errors you will have to have some kind of application-specific handling mechanism.

For everything else use a logging framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), which can log to the Windows Event Log (which can be [monitored remotely via WMI](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MonitoringRemoteLogusingWMI11232005020152AM/MonitoringRemoteLogusingWMI.aspx)) or a remote Syslog server (which is centralised by definition).

Comment: i am not talking about global capturing of application specifc errors. I need something which is global for all my apps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope if [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx) will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

We created just such a service, "BugsVoice", inspired also by your question:

http://bugsvoice.com